# split the string column which has a delimiter(',')-sql

Tags: t-sql

Hi I am trying to split the string column which has a delimiter(',')

```
drop table #address

CREATE TABLE #Address(stir VARCHAR(max));

GO

INSERT INTO #Address(stir)

values('aa,"","7453adeg3","tom","jon","1900-01-01","14155","","2"')

,('ca,"23","42316eg3","pom","","1800-01-01","9999","","1"')

,('daa,"","1324567a","","catty","","756432","213",""')
```

GO

Expected output:

[image]

I am using PARSENAME but it is returning null values?  guide me on my expected out put
thanks in advance

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this in AP?

Comment: SQL Server is very poor to do that.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66592729/sql-server-string-to-m-x-n-table

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here would be to just create a flat CSV file based on your current insert data, and then use SQL Server's bulk import tool to load it into a table.  The following CSV data should be workable here:

```
aa,"","7453adeg3","tom","jon","1900-01-01","14155","","2"
ca,"23","42316eg3","pom","","1800-01-01","9999","","1"
daa,"","1324567a","","catty","","756432","213",""
```

Just make sure that you specify double quote as the field escape character.